# Obtain IP address of a client using Spring Webflux

Tags: java, spring, ip

Since I wasn't able to find any code snippet doing this and also have difficulties finding this on my own I have to ask the community. I consume a REST service and therefore use this code:

```
WebClient
        .builder()
        .baseUrl(baseUrl)
        .build()
        .get()
        .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        .header(HEADER_NAME_APIKEY, apiKey)
        .header(HEADER_NAME_REALM_MANDANT, realmMandant)
        .retrieve()
        .onStatus(HttpStatus::is4xxClientError, clientResponse -> Mono.just(new RuntimeException(String.format("A client error occured: %s", clientResponse.statusCode()))))
        .onStatus(HttpStatus::is5xxServerError, clientResponse -> Mono.just(new RuntimeException(String.format("A server error occured: %s", clientResponse.statusCode()))))
        .bodyToMono(new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<Message>>() {})
        .block()
```

When sending a GET request I end up getting a Connection timeout. After talking to a person on the other side of the endpoint I have been told that the IP needs to be whitelisted before I can consume this service so I am now trying to figure out the IP address of a client/my machine since I try to send this request from my local machine.

Since there is also a proxy on our side I am now unsure which IP I should get whitelisted on the other side. Opening cmd and executing ipconfig to find the IP seems not right to me. Possible way would be maybe to resolve the hostname of the proxy to an IP. I thought that obtaining the IP programmatically right before firing the GET request would be the best solution. So here I am, a bit clueless what to do next.

How can I obtain the IP address using this WebClient object? Is it the right direction I picked or should I stick to resolving the proxy hostname to an IP?

Comment: Which IP address? You are already calling a URL so you already know the location?

Comment: @M.Deinum IP address of a client so my own. Since a proxy is being used I just wanted to sysout the ip

Comment: A client in this context isn't really clear. Also what has a proxy to do with getting the IP address? `InetAddress.getLocalHost()` will give you the machine IP-address, that might and probably will not, be the IP address used externally!.

Comment: @M.Deinum I edited my question to be more clear about what the problem is. Thank you for the quick responses!

Comment: You need to whitelist the ip-address of your gateway/proxy. Adding your machines ip-address won't change a thing as that will be in internal ip-address (generally starting iwth 10.x or 192.x).